# How edit the amounts from a "budgetImport" record in suitscript2.0?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have made a suitelet that groups accounts, but I need to save the results in the budget account lines, I do a record load of "budgetImport", but it does not return the sublist with the amounts, does anyone know how it can be edited from code? ?

```
      var recordExample = record.load({
                    type: 'budgetImport',
                    id: 396,
                    isDynamic: true
                });
    
                recordExample.setSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'budget',
                    fieldId: 'amount_10_',
                    line: 0,
                    value: 310001.00
                });
                var save = recordExample.save()
```

I have tried this but it seems to be not a sublist but a 'lineFields'

Answer (score 0):

There is no sublist value for a budgetImport record.

Although not visible from the UI each budget line (account) has a separate id record.

To set a line in the budgetimport you have to use something like suiteql to find the line id then just update

var recordExample = record.load({
type: 'budgetImport',
id: 11380,
isDynamic: true
});

```
recordExample.setValue({
    fieldId: 'periodamount3',
    value: 16001.00,
})

recordExample.save();
```